# Merging HTML pages (Home, About, Contact,) then displaying them (PHP?) depending on link clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html

To the end-user, it would look like separate pages (index.html, services.html, etc.,) but instead of actually having these documents separate on the server, I'd like to combine them into one and use (I'm assuming) PHP to serve the sections to their own "pages" when their corresponding links are clicked.

For simplicity's sake, say I have the following pages:

1. Home
2. Services
3. Contact

And their code:

Home

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    **Home page content**
<div>
</body>
```

Services

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    **Services page content**
<div>
</body>
```

Contact

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    **Contact page content**
<div>
</body>
```

ETC...

Could I possibly combine them using some markup like:

```
<body>

/*Home markup*/
<?php Script to display this section when "Home" link is clicked; ?>
<div id="content">
    **Home page content**
</div>

/*Services markup*/
<?php Script to display this section when "Services" link is clicked; ?>
<div id="content">
    **Services page content**
</div>

/*Contact*/
<?php Script to display this section when "Contact" link is clicked ?>
<div id="content">
    **Contact page content**
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at template systems, here is a really simple example i've made:

```
function pageSelector(){
    if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        pageSwitch($page);
    } else {
        $_GET['page'] = 'home';
        pageSelector();
    }
}

function pageSwitch($page){
    switch($page){
        case 'home':
            //load home page
        break;
        //add a case for every page you want.
    }
}
```

Just run `pageSelector();` on your index.
you would now make links like this:

```
index.php?page=home
```

where page= is the page you want to access (make sure the page exists in your switch)

Answer (score 0):

You need any identifyer to do that. Maybe like your-domain/home or your-domain/about, etc.

You can use mod_rewrite tu make this to a good locking ID

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

then you can use the switch function to different.

```
function getPage(){
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
        switch(strtolower($_GET['p'])){
            case 'index' : include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../pages/index.php'); break;
            case 'aboutme' : include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/pages/about.php'); break;
            case 'legal' : include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/pages/legal.php'); break;
        }
    }
}
```